# DEP0700: Registration of the app failed UWP in release mode

Tags: c#, uwp, release

After switching the UWP project from debug to release mode, an error appears even SplashScreen.png is included in .appmanifest :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error       DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(32,27): error 0x80070003: Cannot install or update package xxxx_t07g111c25az6 because the splash screen image [SplashScreen.png] cannot be located. Verify that the package contains an image that can be used as a splash screen for the application, and that the package manifest points to the correct location in the package where this splash screen image can be found.  xxxx.App
```

I cleaned and rebuild my project multiple times. Excluding and including project didn't help. Deleting bin and obj folder had no effect. Removing splash screen and adding again, didn't help.

Comment: Please right-click SplashScreen.png in Solution Explorer, select **Properties**. In the Properties window, check if the [Build Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022#build-action-values) is **Content**.